# binary subtraction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary-operations

I am trying to solve binary subtraction:

$$11000_2 - 1011_2 = 1001_2$$

I know that it should be $1001_2$, when checking with answer key however I am not sure how it was calculated as I get different result : $1011_2$, as $0-1$ should give $1$.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: And there should be 1101, if your question has no typos.

Comment: \$18 - \$0b = $0d

Comment: Translation: `24 - 11 = 9` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't forget to "borrow" when subtracting $1$ from $0$.

Here it is in "slow motion:"
\begin{array}{c}
&1&\not1 ^ 0 & \not0^\color{red}1 & \not0^\color{red}1&^10\\
-&&1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
&&&&&1
\end{array}
\begin{array}{c}
&\not 1^0&^10 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}1&^10\\
-&&1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\\hline
&&1&1&0&1
\end{array}

*Note: If the answer key has listed $1001$ as the correct answer, they're wrong... `:)`*

Comment: How come we got 1 instead of 0 in the third place? ( 0f 10110)

Comment: @NadiaS I've added some color to attempt to make that clearer.  Basically, the $1$ that we have "left-over" after borrowing replaces the $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think I understood now!

Answer (score 1):

Computing $1111_2-1011_2$ is easy: you just change each $0$ into $1$ and each $0$ into $1$, getting $0100_2=100_2$. Now adding $1$ is easy as well: you get $101_2$.

I'll leave out the subscript $2$ from now on.

Why is this important? Because you can say
$$
11000-1011=11000+(10000-1011)-10000
$$
and $10000-1011=1+1111-1011=101$ as seen before. Thus we do an addition
$$
\begin{array}{rc}
11000&+\\
101&=\\
\hline
11101
\end{array}
$$
and an easy subtraction
$$
\begin{array}{rc}
11101&-\\
10000&=\\
\hline
1101
\end{array}
$$

Additions are easier than subtraction, because you carry only to the next column (maybe several times), while borrowing can jump several columns away.

Another example: $1001001-10110$. Compute $111111-010110=101001$, so $1000000=101001+1=101010$. Then
$$
\begin{array}{rc}
1001001&+\\
101010&=\\
\hline
1110011&-\\
1000000&=\\
\hline
110011
\end{array}
$$

Final checks:

1. $11000_2=24$, $1011_2=11$; $1101_2=13$.
2. $1001001_2=73$, $10110_2=22$; $110011_2=51$.